# Setting Request Limit in a Meteor.js App

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to send a very large amount of JSON to a server side route in my Meteor.js Application. I keep on getting this error...

Error: Request Entity Too Large
    at Object.exports.error (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:62:13)
    at limit (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/limit.js:46:47)
    at urlencoded (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:58:5)
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:55:7
    at json (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:46:55)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:53:5)
    at next (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.query [as handle] (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:44:5)
    at next (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.Package [as handle] (packages/spiderable/spiderable.js:108)

In my research I have found that I need to set the request limit for the connect middleware.  Does anyone know how I can do this within Meteor? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to add the following code somewhere on the server (e.g., `Meteor.startup`):

```
Router.configureBodyParsers = function() {
  Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '100mb'
  }));
};
```

([ref](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/710))

Answer (score 0):

So after a while of trial and error what ended up working for me was modifying the IronRouter package.  /lib/server/router.js on line 30 change...

```
start: function () {
connectHandlers
  .use(connect.query())
  .use(connect.bodyParser())
  .use(_.bind(this.onRequest, this)); },
```

to...

```
start: function () {
connectHandlers
  .use(connect.query())
  .use(connect.bodyParser({limit: '100mb'})) // or whatever you want your limit to be
  .use(_.bind(this.onRequest, this)); },
```